# Batch script that checks windows services and creates .csv output works when manually initiated, but not when initiated via Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskscheduler

My goal is to have a batch script that checks windows services to see if they're running and output a .csv report. I also want this batch script to run hourly via Windows Task Scheduler.

Here is a script I was given to and am using for the example:

```
type null > servicecheckupreport.csv 
sc query "AdobeARMservice" >> servicecheckupreport.csv 
sc query "aspnet_state" >> servicecheckupreport.csv 
sc query "AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc" >> servicecheckupreport.csv
```

I am checking three (example) services, `AdobeARMservice`, `aspnet_state` and `AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc`.

The batch works fine when you manually execute it, however when I successfully connect it to Windows Task Scheduler using the "Create Basic Task" feature, the batch script runs, but doesn't generate the .csv report. I can see the command prompt come up for a little bit, goes away and then that's it.

Comment: a schedule task will start in another initial folder. Spend it a `cd "%~dp0" to change it to the same folder, where your script resides.

Comment: ...add `/D` to the `cd` command to also change the drive, if necessary...

Comment: You are correct, thanks. I would like to send the .csv to my Y drive. Can I do `sc query "AdobeARMservice" >> Y:\servicecheckupreport.csv` and would it be accepted in Windows Task Scheduler?